# How to formally define a truth table for a First Order Logic Formula?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, solution-verification

Given a function free and quantifier-free First-Order Logic Formula $\phi(X)$. I wish to define the notion of a  truth table over its atoms, and I call it "First Order Truth Table".
My attempt is as follows:

---

First Order Truth Table of a formula $\Phi(X)$ is a truth table  $T_{\Phi}(X)$ with columns defined over atoms of $\Phi(X)$. The rows of $T_{\Phi}(X)$ are truth values assigned to atoms of the formula such that $\Phi(X)$ is satisfied.

---

I will add an example to make clear, what I mean.

$\Phi(x,y) = F(x) \lor F(y)$

The First Order Truth Table is defined as follows,

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
F(x)& F(y) \\ \hline
 T& T \\ \hline
 T& F \\ \hline
 F& T \\ \hline
\end{array}

I wish to verify if the statement I wrote really conveys the idea even without the example. Any help in reformulating it better or feedback on the statement will be much appreciated. $\Phi(X)$ is quantifier-free is apparent from the context of the article I am writing, hence no need to add it in the definition.

Comment: Why not consider the case F-F ? If there is no "link" between the variables $x$ and $y$, the formula is nothing different from $P \lor Q$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am sorry I don't understand what is F-F. And you are right that the formula is no different from $P \lor Q$, but I need to have this formulation of the Truth table, I am sure about the example, I am unsure about if the statement I wrote conveys it.

Comment: False-False.....

Comment: "truth values assigned to atoms of the formula": Which means I am replacing $F(x)$ and $Q(x)$ with truth values.